# Changing levels of factor from colon to row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have made summary table for survey questions where the answers are of 5 or 7 levels Agree,disagree and so on using tbl_summary fron gtsummary but the table is very long. is there any method I can make the table where the levels of the answers are in the columns?

this is my code:

```
table4<-physician[ ,32:43] %>% tbl_summary() %>%  
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols()~"Frequency (%)") %>% 
  modify_caption("** Table 7. The frequency with which prescribers provided antibiotics or resources related to prudent use of antibiotics,
behavior on drivers for initiating prescriptions and antibiotic prescribing behaviors **") %>% 
  modify_header(label~"Item") %>% bold_labels()
```

I want my table to look like this one:

```
Item        SA   A   D   SD  N/A  U  IDU
quesion     56   47  35  89  15   28  10
```

where the question is in the row and the levels and count of each level are in the colons

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to see what your data looks like. If you can, use `dput(physician[1:10, 32:43])` and edit your post with the result. I'm not aware of the ability to pivot wide a gtsummary result, but you can make small tables one row at a time and stack the results.

Comment: Also, I would recommend taking a look at [bstfun](https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html) for using `gtsummary` format with Likert-type scales.

Comment: thanks Ben for your reply but I cant find tbl_likert or bstfun in my R version             R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt) -- "Eye Holes"

Comment: The `tbl_likert` is a function in the `bstfun` package. Did you try to install the `bstfun` package? It is not on CRAN, but you can install the development version, see instructions [here](https://github.com/MSKCC-Epi-Bio/bstfun). You first need to install `devtools` if not available already. If you'd like, I can provide an answer with a complete example using `bstfun` based on what I think is in your data (best would be to provide sample data in your post).

Comment: thanks for your answer it was very helpfull, I could create the table using tbl_likert . can I ask your help to import this table into word document I tried gt and flextable packages but it didnt work with me

Answer (score 0):

It helps to provide example data. Without it, I created a brief example below:

```
set.seed(44)

df <- data.frame(
  question1 = sample(c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", NA), 15, replace = TRUE),
  question2 = sample(c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", NA), 15, replace = TRUE),
  question3 = sample(c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", NA), 15, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Here you will have one column for each question, each containing a Likert-type response answer.

```
           question1         question2         question3
1     Strongly Agree              <NA>    Strongly Agree
2           Disagree Strongly Disagree              <NA>
3           Disagree              <NA>              <NA>
4     Strongly Agree              <NA>             Agree
5  Strongly Disagree    Strongly Agree             Agree
6     Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree          Disagree
7               <NA>             Agree Strongly Disagree
8     Strongly Agree              <NA>              <NA>
9     Strongly Agree              <NA>          Disagree
10             Agree              <NA>             Agree
11             Agree    Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree
12              <NA>    Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree
13    Strongly Agree Strongly Disagree          Disagree
14    Strongly Agree             Agree             Agree
15    Strongly Agree          Disagree Strongly Disagree
```

This might be ideal for the `bstfun` package, that can create `gtsummary` like tables for Likert-type scales. It is not available on CRAN currently, but you can download the development version (I commented out).

```
# devtools::install_github("MSKCC-Epi-Bio/bstfun")

library(bstfun)

tbl_likert(df)
```

**Output**

[image: table with likert type items using bstfun]

Alternatively, you can use `gtsummary` alone. You can create individual table rows and then stack them to create the complete table. You can specify a missing column easily as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

map(
  names(df),
  ~ df |>
    select(all_of(.x)) |>
    mutate(across(all_of(.x), ~fct_na_value_to_level(., "Missing")),
           label_char = TRUE) |> 
    tbl_summary(
      by = all_of(.x),
      statistic = ~"{n}",
      missing = "no",
      label = list(label_char = .x)
    ) |>
    modify_header(
      all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**",
      label = "**Question**"
    )
) |>
  tbl_stack()
```

**Output**

[image: stacked table using gtsummary]

And one more approach that uses `janitor` for adding percentages, and uses `gt` but not `gtsummary` would take a pivoted table and fix up for presentation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(gt)

df |>
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "Question") |>
  tabyl(Question, value) |>
  adorn_percentages("row") |>
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) |>
  adorn_ns(position = "front") |>
  gt()
```

**Output**

[image: table with gt but not gtsummary and using janitor for percent]